# cloudformation update-stack not idempotent

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, terraform

I have a template that creates 2 EC2 instances.

I update the template and remove one of the instances from it

Then i run update stack- cloud formation will not remove that ec2 instance right?

This is why I use terraform. Is there a way to make cloudformation behave this way?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is not correct.

If you remove the EC2 from your Cloudformation template and then update the stack it will delete the EC2 instance